# Prove that if $a$ is irrational then $\sqrt a$ is irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, irrational-numbers

Just hints but solution thx.
Any hints for me? 
I simply suppose that

$a = \dfrac mn$

then $\sqrt a = \sqrt{\dfrac mn}$

But this does not make sense ..

Comment: @ChristophPegel Sorry. Just ignore that I am confused about this question now..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove the contrapositive.

Comment: that is √a is rational then a is rational right?

Comment: @SonicFancy Yes, correct.

Comment: OK I got it. Assuming sqrt(a) = n/m then a is n^2/m^2. Done. thank you I just forget the contrapositive way.

Answer (score 4):

I got the solution.

Assuming that, $\sqrt{a} = \frac{n}{m}$ then we have a is $\frac{n^2}{m^2}$. Obviously this is also a rational number.

Hint from @Git Gud.