# prove that $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}$ is an irrational number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given that $\sqrt{15}$ is an irrational number, prove that $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}$ is an irrational number.

Comment: Consider its square.

Comment: Use the contrapositive of [if $a$ is irrational then $\sqrt a$ is irrational](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/700794/55235).

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Note that $$(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5})^2 = 3 + 2\sqrt{15} + 5 = 8 + 2\sqrt{15}$$

Comment: @Assaultous2 Thanks.

Comment: okay, then what do i do?

Comment: Suppose $(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5})$ is rational for a moment. What happens?

Comment: What happens? I cant figure it out.

Comment: If $x$ is rational, shouldn't $x^2$ be rational?

Comment: Notice that $\mathbb Q$ is a field then if it's closed to its operations. $\sqrt{15} = \frac{(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5})(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5})  - 8}{2}\in \mathbb Q$ which is absurd since you are assuming $\sqrt{15} \in \mathbb R-\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 6):

If $a=\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ is rational so is ${2\over a}=\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}$. Hence $a+{2\over a}=2\sqrt 5$ is a rational number, a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

Assume that $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}=q\in\mathbb{Q}$. Then $\sqrt{15}=\frac{q^2-8}{2}\in\mathbb{Q}$, contradiction.